Issues with Cross-Linking in Amide Bond Formation Reaction – Seeking Advice
I am working on connecting two materials through an amide bond. Currently, the ratio of carboxyl group to amino group is 1:1. I am using EDC/NHS as activators. The post-treatment process is dialysis with ultrapure water followed by lyophilization. However, after lyophilization, my material cross-links directly. Is it because hydroxyl groups compete with amino groups for reaction, turning this material into a cross-linking agent? What methods can be used to prevent cross-linking?

You are working with a hindered amine, that will reduce its nucleophilicity

Do you have any good ways to handle my situation like this? I'm really in need of help.

If the cross-linking is due to -OH groups competing with the hindered amine then a strategy of acylating the free -OH groups before coupling might work

I will give it a try. Thank you for your help
